# How to avoid Hyper ledger Composer Rest server restart while upgrading(with change in model files) composer network installed?

Tags: loopbackjs, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

We have a working setup of 3 peer nodes and a multi user rest server running on 1 of the peers. Now there are multiple user cards created and imported in the rest server(using web based client) which is working fine. I can trigger transactions and query the blockchain with it.

However In case I need to upgrade my network and there is some change in model file(i.e. any participant/asset/transaction parameters changes). I need to restart rest server so that effect can be observed by WEB based client application. So my questions are:
1. Is there a way to upgrade Rest interfaces without restarting the server. 
2. In case Rest server crashed or restarted is there some way to use the old cards that were created before server shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the REST server starts you can see that it "discovers" the Business Network and then generates the End Points.  The discovery is not dynamic, so that when you change the model or other element of a BNA you need to restart the REST server to re-discover the updated network.  (In a live scenario I would think changes to the model are infrequent.)

Are you using multi-user mode for the REST server?  Assuming that you are, then Configuring the REST server with a persistent Data Source as [described in the documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html), or this [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) should solve the problem of re-importing the cards.  You could also "backup" the cards after they have been used the first time by Exporting them.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, Yes we are using the multi user rest server. As of now we are trying to make rest persistent and check if problem is solved or not.                      
But can you elaborate more on second point 'You could also "backup" the cards after they have been used the first time by Exporting them.'. How Exporting card will solve the issue of re-importing the cards, As far as i am thinking it will give me a copy of card but while re-importing it will complain that Rest already has this card imported.

Comment: If you can successfully persist the datasource for the REST server then Exporting the cards doesn't really help - I was just providing an extra suggestion if you were losing cards during testing.

Comment: Hi thanks for clarification, I have successfully completed the persistent activity for rest server and seen that  i can use cards after rest server restart.  Can you please also put some light on rest server and mongo DB behavior in case Machine is restarted/crashed i.e. If restarted the machine will it work same as Rest server restart or do i need to perform any extra step for that.